I want to get 2 exceptions, first a base class and the second one subclass
I want to get 2 exceptions, first a base class and the second one subclass
where is the except ErrorTexto as ET: (right below the variable some_text) I want to get 2 exceptions, like I said in the title, the first is the base, in case the user enters a date that is not inside the choices list, it'll print the base class with the error text ill write, and the second one if the user enters a P letter. I tried putting an if and then the except ErrorTexto, but I didn't get it, it was like this:
some_text = input(f"Escribe un texto, que no lleve la letra P y que este dentro de {choices}\n>_  ")
if "P" in some_text:
    except ErrorTexto as ET:
        if isinstance(ET, ErrorLetra):

but obviously there is a syntax error there, and I don't know how to solve it, right below is the full code:
class ErrorTexto(Exception):
    pass
class ErrorLetra(ErrorTexto):
    pass

try:

    choices = ["Pedro, Joaquin, Celeste, Karen"]
    choices_str = ",".join(choices)
    some_text = input(f"Escribe un texto, que no lleve la letra P y que este dentro de {choices}\n>_  ")
except ErrorTexto as ET:
    if isinstance(ET, ErrorLetra):
        print("No puede llevar la letra P")
    elif ErrorTexto:
        print(f"Tiene que estar dentro de {choices}")

else:
    print("Todo bien")

I tried to use an if

None of your code is going to produce the exceptions you want. Please review how exceptions are raised and handled.

that's why i need help, i dont know how to do it

It sounds like you don't need exceptions, just conditions if you only want to print some messages.

Im using exceptions because i want to master them, but i can't solve this code

I suggest that you write a function which uses if statements to raise both your exceptions and then another which calls the first from within a try/except statement. Your except clauses should catch the most derived exception first, then the base exception next.
